# How to delete orders and customers from a Shopware 6 test store before going productive?

Tags: shopware6

We are launching a new Shopware 6 shop and made some test orders and created test customers.

How to reset those before going productive?

Is there a simple SQL statement or other method for this task?

Comment: You can use following sql statements: 

 - order: https://docs.shopware.com/de/shopware-6-de/tutorials-und-faq/sql-tipps-tricks#alle-bestellungen-loeschen

Or you read all tips and tricks: https://docs.shopware.com/de/shopware-6-de/tutorials-und-faq/sql-tipps-tricks

Answer (score 4):

You can execute

```
delete from cart;
delete from customer;
delete from customer_address;
delete from customer_recovery;
delete from document;
delete from newsletter_recipient;
delete from `order`;
delete from order_address;
delete from order_customer;
delete from product_review;
```

And reset your number ranges to the start values:

```
delete from number_range_state;
```